# How to Show Different View For Selected PickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have some categories and I want to show different text-fields to user for each category.

How can I do this? I tried to add different views in same view controller but I think it's not possible and true way.

[image: my view controllers ss]

Comment: manipulate didselect method.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this function

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    index = row

    if (index == 0)
    {
        //Show a view
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
       //Show another view

    }

    else  if (index == 2)
    {
      //Show another view
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks i know this function but actually i want to show lots different thing for example i want to show 3 label and 3 textfield for one category and 2 label and an image view for another category

Comment: the easiest way is to create three sub views and hide or show them  but i don't think this will be good as a programer  or try to connect these buttons or textfields as an outlet and hide them

Comment: (TWO SUB VIEWS   sorry )But again this is not good So for me i will try to avoid these by using tabbar